# Redirecting a folder request to another folder

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

Here's the situation. I have two WordPress installs. One in the root directory (/) and one in a language subdirectory (/fr/). They also share the same wp_tables, except wp_options (no need to comment on this practice, as I am aware that many people do not recommend it).

Now, I would like the /fr/ WP instance to fetch plugins from the default (root) instance. In other words, every time the /fr/ instance calls for wp-content/plugins, it should fetch its information in ../wp-contents/plugins.

Apache? Htaccess? What to do?

EDIT: my goal is to actually have both instances run on their own domain (and appear as a root folder on their respective domains), on a same server.

www.domain1.com (EN)
www.domain2.com (FR), which in fact is a subfolder (/fr/).

Comment: _“Apache? Htaccess?”_ – neither of those; since there are not HTTP requests involved here, but only files get included via the server file system.

Comment: Is it possible to make so that if you include('/foo/index.php'), it automatically fetches include('/bar/index.php') ?

Comment: The easiest way to achieve that would perhaps be to create a symbolic link in the file system. Assuming that you don’t have SSH/console access, you can [create a symlink using PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.symlink.php) – be careful with the paths though, if you call the function with wrong values, you might have unexpected effects or even do some damage.

Comment: I do have SSH access.
I've tried using `Alias "/var/www/mysite/fr/wp-content/plugins/" "/var/www/mysite/wp-content/plugins/`, to no avail